# Different dependency list for same pom/workspace

Tags: maven, cxf

Anyone any idea why on 2 different PC's who have the exact same workspace (same projects/pom's), same maven version, same OS,  ... same anything that might matter, running mvn dependency:list (or tree) returns a different result?

The actual difference concerns a transitive dependency which on PC A is added to the classpath (and therefore to the dependency-list) and on PC B: not).

UPDATE:
Actually, the problems seems to be restricted to Apache CXF dependencies; almost all their transitive dependencies are missing on PC B.

Comment: Are you using the same Maven version? Same settings etc.?

Comment: @khmarbaise - Yes, 3.0.3; I would have to check the settings but doubt if there's anything in there that could explain this behavior.

Comment: Make sure it's also the same java version.  With CXF, some deps are different if using Java6 compared to Java5.  (need to pull in more deps for java5 whereas it can use built in stuff of Java6)

Comment: Yes, we all use java 5 (I know cxf is integrated into Java 6)

Comment: @Daniel: This is only the case if you use different dependencies (classifier depending on runtime of Java; via profiles). If you just change the runtime this is not the case.

Comment: @TheStijn: Have you cleaned the local repositories and tested again?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Yes, that was one of the things I did. In the mean time I have found the solution, I will post an answer in case someone else runs into this issue (found some posts in other forums but never a solution). Tx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem was related to the java version. Everything was setup for java 5 but Maven itself was running in Java 6. In general this is not a problem but the missing cxf dependencies are included in a profile section of cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:

```
<profile>
    <id>jdk15</id>
    <activation>
        <jdk>1.5</jdk>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
```

So, these dependencies are only added when running Maven in 1.5.
Setting the JAVA_HOME to 1.5 solved the issue.

Comment: @Reddy, just did (you have to wait 2 days before you can accept your own answer).